# Correct approach to get csv data through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

Well this question is all about to get the correct approach, to get the task done.

I have a CSV file with first row as header and which has several columns as

```
| price |  quantity | sold type | adn so on ....
```

and rest row containing values under above headers.

I need to  *type*  in multiselect which i have successfully achieved and  *item price*  and *item sold* value in range slider, that also i have achieved which is shown in the image. Depending on their values i need to display data in the graph.

I have taken out all CSV data and convert it into array with the help of *jquery csv plugin*, which gives me array for each row.

I just want to know the correct approach to do this task ?

[image]

I have got all option in multiselect, set the min max value in sliders, now what i have to do is, based on multiselect and slider values the data in the graph keep on changing whenever multiselect or slider value change based on its availability in the CSV table which i already have in multi dimension array.

Comment: Are you saying what you've already done produces the right output, but you're wondering if there is a better way to do it? There is no one "correct" approach - that's a matter of opinion. In any case it would help if you were to [edit] your question to show the desired output structure.

Comment: i have added an image and describe what is done and what needed to be done in the question.

Comment: Once u can fetch the values from imported file to array or json.. thats the correct way.. here after you can proceed whatever logic is your way and processing and displaying the data only..  so go head..